# Scroll problem sometimes it doesn't work on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, scroll

I'm having a problem with the scroll on my site and I can't understand what's the cause.
Only on Chrome sometimes the scroll doesn't work. I've tried to disable every code I wrote and still there's the problem.
On safari the scroll works fine.

https://mirkomina.com/

It doesn't seem that something specific is triggering the problem, I mean I can't find a specific spot where leaving the cursor triggers the problem.

I've tried to delete all the code I wrote and disable scripts.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using Chrome version v.106.0.5249.120 the scrolling on your site was working just fine. Now you site is protected, so there is not way to keep checking.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, i've found the issue, this was the code:

```
html, body {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    overflow-x: hidden!important;
}
```

And now i've modified it like this:

```
html {
        scroll-behavior: smooth;
        overflow-x: hidden!important;
}
body {overflow-x: hidden;}
```

But still i can't understand why it was generating that issue